# WebView Выбор плеера для проигрывания ролика

Tags: java, android, webview, webbrowser

Написал небольшой браузер, активировал JavaScript, Flash. Понять не могу: когда нажимаю в обычном браузере на видео, то выскакивает окно с выбором, через какой плеер проигрывать видео, когда в своем браузере нажимаю, то этого не происходит. Подскажите, чего не хватает?

Вот код:

```
package com.;
import com.examfple.videodemo.R;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebBrowserAct extends Activity {

    WebView wv;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings(); 
        ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        ws.setSavePassword(true);
        ws.setSaveFormData(true);
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity act = this;

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {

                act.setTitle("Web Браузер");
                act.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    act.setTitle("Готово");
                else{
                    act.setTitle("Загрузка");
                }
            }
        });

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибочка: " + description + " " + failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });

        wv.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

И скриншот прикреплю, как должно быть при нажатии на видеоролик:

[image]